# Always keep caret in the vertical middle of a textarea

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to always keep the caret in the vertical middle of a textarea.

Live example would be the focus mode of IA Writer : when in this mode, the caret is always in the vertical middle, and as soon as you create a new line, the textarea scrolls a little to keep the caret in the middle.

I guess this should be done with JS, and it's fine with me.

Comment: Take a look at this: [iA Writer ported to Javascript. (Webkit only)](https://github.com/icebeat/webwriter).

Answer (score 0):

Try playing with the CSS `line-height`

```
.something {
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 18px;
}
```